# Python class and methods - best practice for accessing and altering attributes?

Tags: python, class, attributes

TLDR: What's best practice for accessing and altering attributes of a class instance?

Let's say we have a class to generate an object that is intended to hold data about a product (e.g. maybe a product master dataset).

```
class StoreProduct(object):

    def __init__(self,ProductID,ProductPrice,ProductDescription):
        self.ProductID = ProductID
        self.ProductPrice = ProductPrice
        self.ProductDescription = ProductDescription


    def ChangeProductPrice(self, newProductPrice):
        self.ProductPrice = newProductPrice
```

And we have another class we may be able to use to access those instances generated by StoreProduct(), with methods for making adjustments / changes.

```
class ChangeProductData(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def ChangeProductObjectPrice(newProductPrice,ProductObject):

        ProductObject.ProductPrice = newProductPrice
```

So we generate an instance named Product1:

```
Product1 = StoreProduct(
    ProductID="Product1",
    ProductPrice=4,
    ProductDescription="A nice lamp"
)
```

What's best practice coding for reading and/or altering class instances?

If I wanted to alter an attribute in Product 1 (in this case the price) is something like this acceptable in general, or is it bad code?

**Method 1**

```
ChangeProductData().ChangeProductObjectPrice(8,Product1)
```

Or is this the preferred way to do it?

**Method 2**

```
Product1.ChangeProductPrice(2)
```

When might there be exceptions?

While the above are simplified situations, what I've currently read seems to indicate that Method 2 might be better practice. However, wouldn't Method 1 provide greater flexibility in future (e.g. if you need to change how a method works, or add new methods).

I have also been reading into getattr() and setattr(), but people seem to be mixed on whether its better than using dot (e.g. Product1.ProductPrice to get the price).

Comment: A `ChangeProductData` class doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why? I understand there are many alternatives (e.g. creating a function instead of a whole class), but I'm specifically tackling the issue of whether accessing and altering an class' attribute with another class is a big no-no.

Comment: A class represents a kind of thing. `ChangeProductData` is not a kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely method 2. As @user2357112 mentions, method 1 doesn't make sense.
As you rightly pointed out, this is a simple scenario and the pythonic way would be use `property`

```
class StoreProduct(object):  # minor: please notice the PEP styling
    def __init__(self, product_price):
        self._price = produce_price
        # other attributes, omitted for brevity

    @property
    def product_price(self):  # pythonic getter
        return self._price

    @product_price.setter
    def product_price(self, new_price):  # python setter
        # you could do any custom validation before setting
        self._price = new_price
```

Coming to the question of

> I'm specifically tackling the issue of whether accessing and altering an class' attribute with another class is a big no-no.

- Accessing: Accessing is okay here. In fact many design patterns that rely on composition heavily do this. e.g., `adapter`, `strategy`, `decorator`, `command` etc patterns
- Altering: You want the class owning the attribute to be in charge of "altering". Foreign classes should only *request to alter*.

P.S. This is treading a bit along the lines of CQRS(Command Query Responsibility Segregation) pattern

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I think I'll need to look further into using property.

What might some of the consequences be for going down the Method 1 route?